# How to show an item with a given index number in QComboBox?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I have added some items in a `QComboBox` and now I am trying to show an item on the `QComboBox` with given index.

For example:

In my `QComboBox`,  I have three items; `firstItem`, `secondItem`, `thirdItem`, when I get an index number two, I want to see `secondItem` shown on the `QComboBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the current index [QComboBox::setCurrentIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop).

```
ui->combo->setCurrentIndex(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set QComboBox to display any item as you choose based on index using `setCurrentIndex()` method.  As an example:

```
....     
artistView = new QComboBox; 
...
index = <some input>;
...
artistView->setCurrentIndex(index);///sets the index
```